# Run php script with webhook

Tags: php

I have php script on my server and app sending webhooks. I need the scenario:
When webhook sent - run php script on my vps.
Webhook is successfully sent (checked with webhook test) but if i put an address of php as a link for webhook it still doesn't run.
Php script is okay. Its just simple fwrite:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
$txt = "John Doe\n"; 
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n"; 
fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
fclose($myfile);
```

What is the problem? Any solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: No idea without seeing the code for the part that calls the webhook and the code for the webhook

Comment: Sorry, just fixed a php script code. Its a simple fopen. Webhook is a notification from shopify.

Comment: Well if that is the webhook code, written in PHP then there is no `<?php` tag to start the interpreter

Comment: There are. Just put code here without them

Comment: Code works perfectly when I open script's path in my browser.

Comment: Then the other end is not calling the webhook

Comment: Or the other end cannot get to your site

Comment: Maybe the russian goverment is blocking access in case any truth should get through to the russian people about whats going on in the Ukraine

Comment: Any solutions? I tried to run my php script from reqbin.net with simple "curl MY SCRIPT ADDRESS" and it works perfectly.

Comment: Probably they do, but how Russia related to any of my webservers?

Comment: You say it's a notification from Shopify - and your profile says you're in Russia, is your web server in Russia? It's _possible_ (though I couldn't say how likely) that Shopify are simply refusing to send the request as they've suspended all operations in Russia for the time being.